# C# Adding an array of RichTextBoxes to an array of TabPages in a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, tabcontrol

[image: Picture of my c# form]

And my code:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace inform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static TabPage[] TabPages = new TabPage[20];
        public static RichTextBox[] TextBoxes = new RichTextBox[20];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TabControl.TabPages.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++)
            {
                TabPages[x].Controls.Add(TextBoxes[x]);    //ERROR HERE
                //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                TabControl.TabPages.Add(TabPages[x]);
                }
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make a basic typing program that uses a tabcontrol to organize each richtextbox in an array. But when I run the program it returns

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have made an array of RichTextBoxes and also TabPages which can both hold 20 elements(is that the right word?) but a problem occurs. The function for Control.Add() is suppose to take a control value.

The for loop is meant to go through each TabPage and add the correct RichTextBox to it.

I have gone onto MSDN to see what they have but all they have is

```
tabPage1.Controls.Add(new Button());
```

instead of my:

```
TabPages[x].Controls.Add(TextBoxes[x]);
```

But even then it does not work, I have done this before but without the the array, the last one I did capped out at 6 tabs and I wanted to make more.
I tried reading some pages on the internet but nothing seemed to work, I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write something like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static TabPage[] TabPages = new TabPage[20];
    public static RichTextBox[] TextBoxes = new RichTextBox[20];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++)
        {
            TabPages[x] = new TabPage();

            TabPages[x].Controls.Add(TextBoxes[x]);    //ERROR HERE
            //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPages[x]);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 for (int a = 0; a < 20;a++ )
        {
            RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();
            TextBoxes[a] = textBox;
            TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
            TabPages[a] = tabPage;
        }
            for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++)
            {
                TabPages[x].Controls.Add(t);    
                TabControl.TabPages.Add(TabPages[x]);
            }
```